# COG tiff interpolated colors and null value

Tags: openlayers

I have built this sample output https://codesandbox.io/s/cog-no-data-interpolate-hhytfw?file=/main.js

I have a COG tiff with no data values, and I have applied it setting `nodata: NaN`.

Then I have applied a color map, but when I applied it, the no data pixels become colored.

How to apply this kind of palette and manage properly the no data pixels?

Thank you

Comment: Speciifying a `nodata` value adds an extra band to the output which can be used as alpha in the style, or as in you case in might be easier to test for if being 0 https://codesandbox.io/s/cog-no-data-interpolate-forked-xu6zjg

Comment: Please add this reply as answer, it's a great answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifying a `nodata` value adds an extra band to the output which can be used as alpha in the style, or when as in you case there is also an interpolation it might be easier to test for it being 0:

https://codesandbox.io/s/cog-no-data-interpolate-forked-xu6zjg